# Store boolean value in UITableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, boolean

How can I store a boolean value in each row of a UITableview. I need to retrieve the boolean value stored in the cell, when that particular cell is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use tag property in `UITableViewCell`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;            
// returns nil if cell is not visible or index path is out of range
{

    static NSString *identifier = @"MyIndetifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }
  //make sure tu put here, or before return cell. 
  cell.tag = 0; //0 =NO, 1=YES;

  return cell;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    BOOL boolean = cell.tag; // return 0 or 1. based on what boolean you set on this particular row.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways:
 1. You can use UITableViewCell.tag property
 2. You can create your own cell class inherited from UITableViewCell and add there normal property for you BOOL value
 3. You can use array associated with your tableview and when you get cell selected, just use indexPath to find associated value in your array
etc.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some other storage, where you keep things like the table cell title or subtitle. Store the boolean there. Use this to convert the bool to something you can put in an array or dictionary.

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
```

For example, if you're using an `NSArray` of strings to store the titles, instead use an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary would have a "title" and (for example) "isActive" boolean (stored as an `NSNumber`).

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableArray *tableData;

every table cell associate with a NSMutableDictionary store in tableData,
you can set a NSNumber(store bool) to the Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement method of UITableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;            
// returns nil if cell is not visible or index path is out of range
{
 //create cell here
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }
  return cell;
}
```

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //by using indexpath.row you can access the cell on which user clicked.
  }